# Extend Nest query with a filter

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a lot of search methods, all of them use same method to perform query. The content of this shared method looks like this:

```
var result = await this.GetClient(requestContext).SearchAsync<TEntity>(r => queryBuilder(r, @params, requestContext).Skip(@params.Skip).Size(@params.Take));
```

I need to apply some filtration for all search methods (need to filter by deletedUtc field). My idea is to extend existing query (result of queryBuilder). But I can't find obvious solution. Any attempt to do something like this

```
...queryBuilder(r, @params, requestContext).Query(a => a.DateRange(rng => rng.Field(e => e.DeletedUtc).GreaterThan(DateMath.Now))
```

rewrites query itself. PostFilter is not something I am looking for, I want to exclude deleted items from any query or aggregation. Thanks.